# how to force the Clint to focus on input filed on javascript

Tags: javascript, input

i need to set the Clint focus on my input filed 
      `<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onfocusout="myFunction8()">`
onfoucseout, and i want it to focus at cirtain place on the input (for exaple, position 2: "he[cursor]llo")

```
function myFunction8()
         {
         var str = document.getElementById("fname")
         var l = str.length
         var l = 0
         var n = 0
         var d = 0
         var s=0
         if (l < 5) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position 0
         }
         else {
             for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                 if ((str.charAt(i)) = "@") {
                     l++;
                     n = i
                 }
                 if ((str.charAt(i)) = ".") {
                     d++
                     l = i
                 }
             }
         }
         if (l == 0) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position 1
         }
          if (d == 0) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position 3
         }
         if (l > 1) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position n
         }
         if ((l - n) < 2) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position n+1
         }
         if (n==0) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position 0
         }
         if (l==0) {
             //the carsure will be foucused in position 0
         }


    }
```

note: [this articel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892201/force-focusing-on-sibling-input) was not helful becuse it not using vanila js
and: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field) as well as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) was not helpful becuse they  fouce non foucing the curscur on the input fhils, but not use the exact position

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

checkout this one

```
 function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos) {
  if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
     ctrl.focus();
     ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
  } else if(ctrl.createTextRange) {  //this is for old browsers
     var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
     range.collapse(true);
     range.moveEnd('character', pos);
     range.moveStart('character', pos);
    range.select();
  }
}
myFunction8(){
  var input = document.getElementById('fname');
  setCaretPosition(input, length);  
}
```

Comment: where can i choose witch position to focus

Comment: myFunction8(){
  var input = document.getElementById('fname');  var input = document.getElementById('fname');

  setCaretPosition(input, 3);  
} it will set cursor at position 3